# C# UWP Read from dragged file

Tags: c#, uwp, drag-and-drop

I have a little problem:

I tried to read the text from a drag/dropped file, but I don't get access to the file.
I don't really know what I did wrong.
Is there a way to get the access to the file?

My code:

```
if (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.StorageItems))
{
    var items = await e.DataView.GetStorageItemsAsync();
    if (items.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var appFile in items.OfType<StorageFile>())
        {
            string text = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(appFile);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `GetStorageItemsAsync()` return `IReadOnlyList<IStorageItem>` just iterate them and get file from `IStorageItem.Path`. [IStorageItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.istorageitem?view=winrt-19041), [GetStorageItemsAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datapackageview.getstorageitemsasync?view=winrt-19041#Windows_ApplicationModel_DataTransfer_DataPackageView_GetStorageItemsAsync)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one should to work.

```
if (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.StorageItems))
{
    foreach (IStorageItem TargetStorageItem in await DroppedDataInfo.GetStorageItemsAsync())
    {
        if(TargetStorageItem is StorageFile)
        {
            string text = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(TargetStorageItem as StorageFile);
            //Read only this first one in this case...
            break;
        }
    }
}
```